# sql, return only the max version of a record from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max

I have the following table which has a few key fields. the most important being the version and the dates.
[image]
I need a query that will allow me to display the active prices in the system for each of the company and products.

so show all dates between start and end, easy enough
show only the maximum version with those results - this is where I am stuck.

I have created a fiddle to show my example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0d4f/3

how can I return only the record for each company and product that has the highest version within the date ranges?

this is what I have so far but incomplete:

```
select * from 
prices
where getdate() between [start] and [end] 
--and max(version)
```

Comment: You've no primary key for your table?

Comment: just an example thanks, there is definitely a primary key

Comment: @Joël Salamin: Primary key is likely to be company + product + version. How do you get the idea there is none? And what difference does it make for the problem given?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I've got a look on your `sqlfiddle` and the `CREATE` statement is not defining a PK. I was looking for a solution to your problem using an `INNER JOIN` and it was a bit more complicated without the info about a PK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH PricesCTE AS
(
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY companyid,product ORDER BY version DESC) AS rn
  FROM   prices
  WHERE  GETDATE() BETWEEN [start] AND [end]
)
SELECT * 
FROM   PricesCTE 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0d4f/34)**

Comment: This is a good way to do it. You forgot, however, to add the WHERE clause to only show current prices.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This is what i saw after reading your answer. I got comfused because if you see the expected results in the right screenshot they match with mine. I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First find the highest version per product for the desired date. Then join with your table to get that record.

```
select * 
from 
(
  select companyid, product, max(version) as max_version 
  from prices
  where getdate() between [start] and [end]
  group by companyid, product
) this_date 
inner join prices
  on prices.companyid = this_date.companyid
  and prices.product = this_date.product 
  and prices.version = this_date.max_version;
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0d4f/32.